# Confusion with freeing memory in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, gdb, malloc, free

I am thoroughly confused as to what I am doing wrong here. I have a linked list of nodes (see below for the structures) and I'm confused as to how to free the memory when trimming the list. I thought that adding them to an array (`eventArr`) would make them easier to free later, but I am still having issues! Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```
static void trim_list(int room, int keep, char timestamp[]) {

        struct room_t *the_room;
        struct room_t *the_room_copy;

        struct evnode_t *eventArr[20];
        int index = 0;

        the_room_copy = malloc(sizeof(struct room_t));
        the_room = find_room(room);

        the_room_copy->room = the_room->room;
        the_room_copy->ecount = the_room->ecount;
        the_room_copy->evl_head = the_room->evl_head;

        struct evnode_t *node;

        int counter;
        int removed = 0;

        for(counter = 0; counter != keep; counter++){
          the_room_copy->evl_head = the_room_copy->evl_head->next;                 
        }

        while(the_room_copy->evl_head){
          eventArr[index] = the_room_copy->evl_head;
          the_room_copy->evl_head = the_room_copy->evl_head->next;
          index++;
          removed++;
        }

        for(index = 0; index < removed; index++){
          free(eventArr[index]);
        }

        printf("Trim log @ %s: room %i log trimmed to length %i (%i entries removed)\n",timestamp, room, keep, removed);

        return ;
}
```

Structs:

```
struct evnode_t {
        struct event_t event ;
        struct evnode_t *next ;
} ;

struct room_t {
        int room ;
        int ecount ;
        struct evnode_t *evl_head ;
        struct room_t *next_room ;
} ;

struct event_t {
        int sensor ;
        char time_stamp[MAX_TIMESTRING+1];
        int event_id ;
        int event_info ;
} ;
```

I should note that I ran this through gdb in order to understand it better, but the values are getting all messed up for some reason. Here is my output from that:

Before running trim_list...

```
(gdb) p room_list->room
$1 = 1
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->event.sensor
$2 = 9
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->event.sensor
$3 = 4
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->next->event.sensor
$4 = 2
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->next->next->event.sensor
$5 = 2
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->next->next->next->event.sensor
$6 = 3
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->next->next->next->next->event.sensor
$7 = 2
```

after running trim_list...

```
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->event.sensor
$8 = 4
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->next->event.sensor
$9 = 2
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->next->next->event.sensor
$10 = 2
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->next->next->next->event.sensor
$11 = 0
(gdb) p room_list->evl_head->next->next->next->next->next->event.sensor
$12 = 6396880
```

Any insight as to why I'm getting these issues would be so helpful! I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly how to free values... however I do know that the values being freed have all been `malloc`ed. To clarify, `room_list` is the list that I am trying to free the values from, and `the_room_copy` is a newly `malloc`ed version of `room_list`.

Comment: What parameters have you passed to trim_list for the output of gdb?

Comment: parameters room = 1, keep = 4, timestamp = "12:50:00"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are freeing the nodes correctly.  What you **aren't** doing is terminating the list at the new location.  For example, if the old list was:

```
1 -> 9 -> 4 -> 2 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> NULL
```

And you want to trim after the 5th element, what you are doing now ends up like this:

```
1 -> 9 -> 4 -> 2 -> 2 -> (freed memory) -> (unknown pointer) -> ...
```

What you need to do is terminate the linked list after the ones you want to keep:

```
1 -> 9 -> 4 -> 2 -> 2 -> NULL
```

Here is some sample code showing one way of terminating the list:

```
    struct evnode_t *end_of_list = NULL;

    // This is your existing loop to skip past "keep" elements.
    for(counter = 0; counter != keep; counter++){
      end_of_list = the_room_copy->evl_head;
      the_room_copy->evl_head = the_room_copy->evl_head->next;                 
    }

    // Free stuff as you did before...

    // At the very end:
    if (end_of_list == NULL) {
        // Keep nothing.
        the_room->evl_head = NULL;
    } else {
        // Terminate the list at the proper place.
        end_of_list->next = NULL;
    }

    // Oh, you need to free the copy also, it's a memory leak:
    free(the_room_copy);
```

Comment: Hmm okay. So I need to run a cursor through my list to the freed memory location and make that null?

Comment: @ColinFausnaught You already did that in your loop to skip past the "keep" elements.  So you already passed up the node to null out in that loop.  Maybe I'll add some code to show you.

Comment: Please do I'm still a little confused. I'm not sure I understand how my new `malloc`ed value and room_list interact.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of Mr. JS1, to terminate the linked list you will want to add code resembling this :

```
struct evnode_t *node_to_terminate = the_room->evl_head;
for (int i = 1; i < keep; ++i)
{
    node_to_terminate = node_to_terminate->evl_head;
}

node_terminate->next = NULL;
```